# Dozer Mapper is not mapping composed nested fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config, dozer

Tools/Frameworks in use:

- `JDK 1.7`
- `Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE`
- `Dozer 5.5.1`

**Class: BaseModel.java**

```
package com.demo.model;
public class BaseModel {
  protected Long createdBy;
  protected Timestamp createdTimestamp;
  protected Long updatedBy;
  protected Timestamp updatedTimestamp;
  protected Long revision;
  // ... Getters/Setters
}
```

**Class: Author.java**

```
public class Author {
  private BaseModel baseModel;
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  // Getter of baseModel
  public BaseModel getBaseModel() {
    return baseModel == null ? new BaseModel() : baseModel;
  }
  // ... Other Getters/Setters
}
```

**Class: BasePojo.java**

```
package com.demo.web.pojo;
public class BasePojo {
  protected Long createdBy;
  protected Timestamp createdTimestamp;
  protected Long updatedBy;
  protected Timestamp updatedTimestamp;
  protected Long revision;
  // ... Getters/Setters
}
```

**Class: AuthorPojo.java**

```
package com.demo.web.pojo;
public class AuthorPojo extends BasePojo {
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  // Getters/Setters
}
```

**Class: SpringConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan("com.demo")
public class SpringConfig {

}
```

**Class: DemoDozerMapper.java**

```
@Component("demoDozerMapper")
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class DemoDozerMapper extends DozerBeanMapper {
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
  logger.info("PostConstruct called....");
    this.initMappings();
  }

  private void initMappings() {
  final BeanMappingBuilder authorMappingBuilder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      mapping(Author.class, com.demo.web.pojo.Author.class, 
           TypeMappingOptions.mapId("authorMap"),
           TypeMappingOptions.mapNull(true), TypeMappingOptions.oneWay())
                .fields("baseModel.createdBy", "createdBy")
                .fields("baseModel.createdTimestamp", "createdTimestamp")
                .fields("baseModel.updatedBy", "updatedBy")
                .fields("baseModel.updatedTimestamp", "updatedTimestamp");
            }
        };

        addMapping(authorMappingBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Class: Demo.java**

```
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ApplicationContext springAppContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
    final Mapper dozerMapper = springAppContext.getBean("demoDozerMapper", DemoDozerMapper.class);

    final Author authorModel = new Author();
    authorModel.getBaseModel().setCreatedBy(Long.valueOf(1L));
    authorModel.getBaseModel().setCreatedTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    authorModel.setFirstName("First");
    authorModel.setLastName("Last");
    authorModel.setId(Long.valueOf(21101L));

    final com.demo.web.pojo.Author author = new com.demo.web.pojo.Author();
    dozerMapper.map(authorModel, author);
    System.out.println("Author Pojo: " + author);
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Author Pojo: AuthorPojo {id=21101, firstName=First, lastName=Last, createdBy=null, createdTimestamp=null, updatedBy=null, updatedTimestamp=null, revision=null}
```

The fields `createdTimestamp` and `createdBy` are not mapped from model to pojo. Am I doing anything wrong? Could someone help?

Comment: It looks like you're never setting the `baseModel` object on the `authorModel`, therefore `Author.getBaseModel()` is returning a new instance of `BaseModel` each time the getter is called but that instance never gets set on the Author object that is being converted. If you explicitly create an instance of `BaseModel` and set the `createdBy` and `createdTimestamp` on that then set that instance on the `authorModel` object in Demo.java does that work?

Comment: Hi @IanA, I tried your approach (created an instance of `BaseModel` explicitly, then setting these `createdBy` and `createdTimestamp` in it and then, setting this to `authorModel`; it still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had another look after my comment above. As well as changing the way the `baseModel` is set on `authorModel`, you also need to ensure you're calling the mapper passing the in the id corresponding to the mapping you defined in DemoDozerMapper.java (i.e. `authorMap`) - see [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/contextmapping.html) for details on context based mapping in Dozer.

The revised Demo.java should look like this:

**Class: Demo.java**

```
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ApplicationContext springAppContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
    final Mapper dozerMapper = springAppContext.getBean("demoDozerMapper", DemoDozerMapper.class);

    final Author authorModel = new Author();

    // Ensure base model is set
    BaseModel baseModel = new BaseModel();
    baseModel.setCreatedBy(Long.valueOf(1L));
    baseModel.setCreatedTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    authorModel.setBaseModel(baseModel);

    authorModel.setFirstName("First");
    authorModel.setLastName("Last");
    authorModel.setId(Long.valueOf(21101L));

    final AuthorPojo author = new AuthorPojo();

    // Select the appropriate case to use
    dozerMapper.map(authorModel, author, "authorMap");
    System.out.println("Author Pojo: " + author);
  }
}
```

**Revised Output**

```
Author Pojo: AuthorPojo [id=21101, firstName=First, lastName=Last, createdBy=1, createdTimestamp=2015-11-26 10:07:31.501, updatedBy=null, updatedTimestamp=null, revision=null]
```

Comment: Thanks @IanA, this worked. I have accepted this as the solution for my question.